# Como cargar información del modelo en un Modal Bosstrap C#

Tags: c#, bootstrap

Necesito que antes de eliminar un registro validar con un modal si el usario si lo desea eliminar.

Todo funciona perfecto exepto que el modal siempre me reconoce el primer registro de la tabla como el ID de ese registro... Ejemplo quiero Eliminar la factura 85, cuando le doy clic en confirmar la eliminación me dice que si deseo eliminar la factura 52 (El primer registro de la tabla)

El Modal lo estoy llamando desde este Boton.. El cual esta dentro de un Foreach que recorre cada Item del Modelo.

Codigo Modal

×
                                        Eliminar Factura

¿Esta Seguro que desea eliminar la factura N° @item.NumeroFactura ?

Eliminar
                                        Cancelar

CODIGO COMPLETO

```
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Facturas", new {id = item.IDFactura })" title="Ver Factura">@item.NumeroFactura</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Entidades", new {id = item.IDEntidad })" title="Ver Informacion del cliente">@item.EntidadesNombre</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.Fecha.ToShortDateString()
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.FechaVencimiento.ToShortDateString()
                </td>
                <td>
                    @string.Format("${0:N0}", item.TotalNeto)
                </td>

                <td>
                    @string.Format("${0:N0}", item.ValorAbonado)
                </td>
                @*por pagar pendiente hacer la resta*@
                <td>
                    @string.Format("${0:N0}", item.TotalNeto - item.ValorAbonado)
                </td>

                <td>
                    @item.EstadoNombre
                </td>
                @*Acciones de los botones*@
                <td>
                    <a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "Facturas", new {id = item.IDFactura })" class="btn btn-toolbar btn-xs" title="Editar Factura"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
                    <a class="btn btn-toolbar btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalVerfactura" title="Ver detalle de la factura"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></a>
                    @*<a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Facturas", new {id = item.IDFactura })" class="btn btn-toolbar btn-xs" title="Ver Detalle Factura"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></a>*@
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-toolbar btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print" title="Imprimir Factura"></span></a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-toolbar btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd" title="Pagar Factura"></span></a>
                    <a class="btn btn-toolbar btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalEliminarfactura" title="Eliminar factura" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
                    <!-- Modal Eliminar Factura-->
                    <div id="ModalEliminarfactura" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">

                            <!-- Modal content-->
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title">Eliminar Factura</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <p>¿Esta Seguro que desea eliminar la factura N° @item.NumeroFactura ?</p>

                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <a href="@Url.Action("Delete", "Facturas", new {id = item.IDFactura})" class="btn btn-default" title="Eliminar Factura">Eliminar</a>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>



                    <!-- Modal Ver Factura-->
                    <div id="ModalVerfactura" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

                            <!-- Modal content-->
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title">Factura N° @item.NumeroFactura</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body" data-toggle="@Url.Action("Details", "Facturas", new {id = item.IDFactura })" data-target="@Url.Action("Details", "Facturas", new {id = item.IDFactura })">
                                    <p>contenido</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">

                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </td>
            </tr>
        }
```

Comment: se parece que hay un error en el foreach. Para ayudar mas, debes poner ese parte tambien

Comment: Ya monte el código completo

Comment: Ya veo el problema. Dame unos minutos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema major es que en cada forloop estas construyendo un modal con el nombre "ModalEliminarfactura"

Cuando llamas el modal, abre el primero que se encuentra.

Entonces, tienes algunos opciones. El mas facil es cambiar los nombres a algo como `<div id="ModalEliminarfactura@(item.IDFactura)" class="modal fade" role="dialog">` y el anchor

```
<a class="btn btn-toolbar btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalEliminarfactura@(item.IDFactura)" title="Eliminar factura" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
```

Pero si solo quieres un modal, el solucion abajo es mejor:

Cambia a un onclick en vez de data-toggle

```
<a class="btn btn-toolbar btn-xs" title="Eliminar factura" onclick="EliminarFactura(@(item.IDFactura))" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
```

Y cambia el modal con un input hidden

```
<div id="ModalEliminarfactura" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <input type="hidden" id="eliminarFacturaId" value="0" />
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Eliminar Factura</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>¿Esta Seguro que desea eliminar la factura N° @item.NumeroFactura ?</p>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a href="ProcesaEliminarFactura()" class="btn btn-default" title="Eliminar Factura">Eliminar</a>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

El JQuery es asi:
Para abrir el modal

function EliminarFactura(id){
    $("#eliminarFacturaId").val(id);
    $("#ModalEliminarfactura").modal("show");
}

Para llamar delete

function ProcesaEliminarFactura(id){
    location.href = "/Facturas/Delete/" + $("#eliminarFacturaId").val();
}

Comment: Gracias, utilice repetir el Modal y me funciono!